# Why does my Rust application have different behaviour for each distinct optimisation level?

Tags: winapi, rust

I have a Rust program that behaves differently depending on what level of optimisation is applied. It's a simple program that displays a Win32 `MessageBoxW`.

Here's the output at `opt-level = 0`:

[image]

Here's the output at `opt-level = 1`:

[image]

Here's the output at `opt-level = 2`:

[image]

A minimal reproducible example of the program follows. It's not quite the same because my binary is `no_std` (hence I'm using the `alloc` crate), but the behaviour is similar for each of the optimisation levels.

```
extern crate alloc;

use std::{
    ffi::{c_char, c_int, c_uint},
    ptr::null_mut,
};

pub enum HWND__ {}
pub type HWND = *mut HWND__;

pub type DWORD = u32;
pub type LPCCH = *const c_char;
pub type LPCWSTR = *const u16;
pub type LPWSTR = *mut u16;
pub type UINT = c_uint;

pub const CP_UTF8: DWORD = 65001;
pub const MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS: DWORD = 0x08;
pub const MB_OK: UINT = 0x00000000;

macro_rules! wide_str {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {{
        let utf8 = alloc::fmt::format(format_args!($($arg)*));
        const BUFFER_LEN: usize = 256;
        let utf16: &[u16; BUFFER_LEN] = {
            let mut utf16 = [0; BUFFER_LEN];

            let result = MultiByteToWideChar(
                CP_UTF8,
                MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
                utf8.as_ptr() as LPCCH,
                utf8.len() as core::ffi::c_int,
                utf16.as_mut_ptr() as LPWSTR,
                utf16.len() as core::ffi::c_int,
            );
            assert!(result != 0, "error converting utf8 to utf16");

            &{ utf16 }
        };
        utf16.as_ptr()
    }};
}

#[link(name = "kernel32")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn MultiByteToWideChar(
        CodePage: UINT,
        dwFlags: DWORD,
        lpMultiByteStr: LPCCH,
        cbMultiByte: c_int,
        lpWideCharStr: LPWSTR,
        cchWideChar: c_int,
    ) -> c_int;
}

#[link(name = "user32")]
extern "system" {
    pub fn MessageBoxW(hWnd: HWND, lpText: LPCWSTR, lpCaption: LPCWSTR, uType: UINT) -> c_int;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        MessageBoxW(
            null_mut(),
            wide_str!("Message!"),
            wide_str!("Caption!"),
            MB_OK,
        );
    }
}
```

Why does this difference in output happen and how can it be fixed?

Comment: If someone feels strongly enough that the `winapi` tag is inappropriate here, I'm happy to remove it.

Comment: welcome to the world of undefined behavior, take a seat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointers created by `wide_str!` are dangling since `utf16` (both inner and outer variables with the same name) is destroyed before `MessageBoxW` is even called. This behavior is undefined; it could break and cause inconsistencies like this or even worse it can appear to work but be broken later or in more subtle ways.

To avoid future misuse, I would suggest returning a value from your macro that *owns* the data, from which you can call `.as_ptr()` manually. Something like this:

```
macro_rules! wide_str {
    ($($arg:tt)*) => {{
        let utf8 = alloc::fmt::format(format_args!($($arg)*));
        const BUFFER_LEN: usize = 256;
        let mut utf16 = [0; BUFFER_LEN];

        let result = MultiByteToWideChar(
            CP_UTF8,
            MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
            utf8.as_ptr() as LPCCH,
            utf8.len() as core::ffi::c_int,
            utf16.as_mut_ptr() as LPWSTR,
            utf16.len() as core::ffi::c_int,
        );
        assert!(result != 0, "error converting utf8 to utf16");

        utf16
    }};
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        MessageBoxW(
            null_mut(),
            wide_str!("Message!").as_ptr(),
            wide_str!("Caption!").as_ptr(),
            MB_OK,
        );
    }
}
```

This does not exhibit the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: winapi is the tag for Win32, unless I’m mistaken, not the Rust crate of a similar name. I don’t think I’d do it this way for a work related app but I’m hoping to dig deeper in a number of areas with this project which is made easier by not using windows-rs.

Comment: @junglie85 If its just for your own exploration, by all means keep doing what you're doing. But I bring it up because `no_std` implies your code will work without an operating system, but you link directly to Windows so your code isn't `no_std`. Its just odd.

Comment: If windows crate gets in the way, you can consider using the windows-sys crate

Comment: no-std means only "no standard library". Although it is often used in "no OS" (aka baremetal) programming, it is perfectly viable for an OS environment as well (consider driver development).

Comment: One of the things I’m using the project to learn is how Rust interacts with the OS, how the standard library is implemented (and just how much value it adds to Rust when you can use it), and how crates such as windows-sys can be implemented. Using the crates specifically doesn’t make sense and ‘no_std’ forces some things that wouldn’t be exposed otherwise such as allocators, panic and alloc error handling, facilities provided by the C runtime. I don’t want to write a whole OS otherwise Phil Opp’s blog would suit.

Comment: If you don't want to use the *windows* or *windows-sys* crates you can still take inspiration from [their implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/blob/master/crates/libs/sys/src/core/literals.rs#L9-L36) of the [`w!`](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/0.45.0/windows_sys/macro.w.html) macro. It is fundamentally different in that it generates a compile-time slice constant, with unbounded lifetime, thereby making it impossible for pointers to start dangling.

Comment: *"As a side note, using `no_std` and winapi seems very **weird**"* - Actually, no. When using the Standard Library the panic strategy defaults to `'unwind'`. Which is pretty dangerous (and UB) in functions that cross into foreign code on exit (such as a window procedure callback). Using `no_std` opts out of this behavior. You could also explicitly set `panic = 'abort'` for all profiles, but using `no_std` in a Windows application isn't all that crazy. It's not a coincidence that *windows-sys* comes with the `#![no_std]` attribute.

Comment: I've removed the section about `no_std` since it seems I was wrong and it was irrelevant to the answer anyway.